# retrieve id from dropdown/select box codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Im trying to figure how to retrieve the ID number from a selected value in a dropbox, displaying a list of projects from a table.

At this point what i did was retrieve the value and then search it and get the ID number for that value in the table. Well the field name_project it's "unique" so it's not so bad but i want to retrive the id directly without querying the database offcourse! It's really necessary the use of jquery or javascript to do that?

```
<?php echo form_open('solucao/inserir',array('class' => 'form-horizontal')); ?>
 <select class="form-control" id="project" name="project">
                            <option>--Choose Project--</option>
                            <?php foreach($projects as $data):?> 
                            <option><?php echo $data->name_project?></option>
                            <?php endforeach;?>  
                            </select>
<?php form_close(); ?>
```

Note: $data is an array wich contains the ID number!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have project_id and project_name as field names in your project table

In model:

```
function getProjectArr()
{
    $res =  $this->db->get("project");
    $ret_arr = array();
    if($res-<num_rows()>0)
    {
       foreach($res->result() as $r)
       {
          $ret_arr[$r->project_id] = $r->project_name;
       }
    } 
    return $ret_arr;
}
```

In your controller,

```
$data["project_list"] = $this->MODEL_NAME->getProjectArr();
```

In View file

```
echo form_dropdown("project",$project_list,'','id="project" class="form-control"');
```

You will get dropdown with ids as option value and names as option text.

Comment: @Kumar V, Hi! How can I submit/print_r id `project_id` from $project_list? I don't know how to specifically access `project_id`. Please reply I didn't find simple solution. TIA

Comment: @fWd82 $project_list will have array of object. You can run a loop and then individual object can be accessed with its object name.

Answer (score 0):

When you will get the id on select or options tag.

Then get the `id` of selected option you can use something like this.

```
document.getElementById('project').addEventListener('change', selectId);
function selectId(){
    alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].id);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/my79q/1/)

**OR**

Get the id of select tag then you can use

```
document.getElementById('project').addEventListener('change', selectId);
function selectId(){
    alert(this.id);
}
```

[**Demo2**](http://jsfiddle.net/my79q/2/)

Comment: humm i could echo the id_number into each select id, but how could i submit that id to my controller?

Comment: I think you will have to submit the form on selection of value.